# Highlight region while typing

Tags: emacs

Let's say you are about to type something that you know you want to kill-yank later. For example, say we need to repeat the following 10 times:

```
grid.addValue([some variable])
```

Currently, before I start typing, I can press `C-<spc> C-<spc>` to activate then deactivate the mark at the beginning of the text. Then, once I finish typing `grid.addValue()`, I can press `C-x C-x` twice to go back to the original mark, then back to the end of the text with the text highlighted.

My question: is there a way to set the mark and highlight as I type, so when I am done with the phrase I can immediately copy and yank it a bunch of times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the mark, type, and then copy/kill as normal.

The region (i.e. whatever is between point and mark) isn't highlighted, but it's still usable.